# How was the AeroVironment Helios able to fly to the edge of space at no more than 23.5 kn?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, stall, high-altitude, nasa

The [NASA/AeroVironment Helios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AeroVironment_Helios_Prototype) holds the FAI record for the highest *sustained horizontal* flight at 96,900 ft (29.5 km) MSL. It reportedly spent more than 40 min above 96,000 ft. It could fly no faster than 23.5 knots, hence those records are extremely hard to believe. What is its stall speed? How could it fly that high on two-blade-propellers? Could it carry a human who'd lay on its middle into the stratosphere?

And since the Helios, the Pathfinder and the Centurion were meant to be test atmosats, are there any images from the edge of space by them? I couldn't find any.

Comment: By god how many Giovannis we have here?

Comment: @Jpe61 All Giovannis are the same person, except for the user Robert DiGiovanni who's a different user.

Comment: @mins But that's a glider. Did the Helios use lifts gliders use as well, such as wave lift?

Comment: User page states "member for 2 days", that does not compute. As for the speed, why is it not plausible?

Comment: @Jpe61 Because when I ask a question on another SE site, and on aviation again, I'd have a new account here. The speed doesn't sound plausible because aircraft stall at much higher speeds, even near sea level. Hence my question what's different for the Helios than for other planes?

Comment: Ok, I understand the premise of the question now.

Comment: You do realize you can use same SE account on all SE sites? No need to create new accounts?

Comment: @Jpe61 The new account is being created automatically, by posting a question or answer in another SE.

Comment: In case you haven't been keeping up with the space news, NASA is currently flying a helicopter on Mars, where the pressure altitude is 100K ft or more: https://mars.nasa.gov/technology/helicopter/#Quick-Facts

Comment: @jamesqf Yes but that's a helicopter/drone, it rarely has any horizontal speed, Ingenuity mostly flies vertically. I'm talking about planes. Airplanes need to fly somewhat horizontally to fly (up), unless they have hover engines like the Harrier. The atmosphere of Mars is denser btw because it's carbon dioxide which is denser than the Earth's air composition.

Comment: @mins I wrote _edge_ of space on purpose, but the 100-km-boundary is wrong (it's _not_ "the" Kármán line) and exaggerately high anyway. There's no abrupt border between the atmosphere and the vacuum of space, you have to define one. You may define it at a layer border such as the stratopause. At 30 km (100k ft) the sky is pitch black and you see the brightest stars and the Earth's curvature. When I.C. Kincheloe flew to 126k ft in the X-2 in 1956 he was declared the first man in space.

Comment: @Giovanni: Space density limit is indeed a convention and varies according to the needs, 100 km for the limit of wing lift generation and balloon buoyancy, and 122 kilometers for spacecraft reentry interface. So at 80 km, lift generation is still possible, at 140 it's not. At 30 km, or when you're flying, you're nowhere in space according to conventions.

Comment: @mins Balloons can't fly higher than ~60 km (200k ft). Wing lift generation (and therefore the Kármán line) depends on the mass and density of the planet in question, not just the atmosphere, so it cannot be universal. For Earth the average value is 83.6 km above sea level. The Helios reached 29.5 km and no non-rocket plane flew higher in sustained horizontal flight (unless you count the X-43 which flew at 33.5 km).

Comment: @Giovanni: The blades on a helicopter rotor are airfoils, just like wings and propellor blades.  And while CO2 is somewhat denser than Earth's mostly N2 & O2 mix, it's not dense enough to offset the fact that there's only about 1% as much of it.

Comment: @jamesqf Well, but it are _rotating_ airfoils and they're four blades, the Helios has two blades each. Additionally, Mars' gravity is 3/8 that of Earth's.

Comment: @mins BBC considers the U2 at 70,000 ft flying at the edge of space, and the pilot does so too: https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20140224-flying-at-the-edge-of-space

Comment: "*BBC considers the U2 at 70,000 ft flying at the edge of space, and the pilot does so too*". That's good news for future low altitude space stations.

Comment: @mins You mean stratospheric balloons/airships which offer accomodation (say a large version of Space Perspective's Neptune)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*My answer will be a simplified one, someone with more theoretical wisdom and keyboard can expound (tapping on phone screen does not encourage long answers with fancy formatting).
All my data is retrieved from Wikipedia site.*

There is nothing strange in Helios HP01's flight regime, in speed nor altitude.

The speed range is mentioned to be 16.5–23.5 kts. Stall speed is not specified.

The reasons for slow operating speed is the selected wing profile that is optimized for slow speeds, and extremely low wing loading. HP01 weighs less than 1000kg, and has wing area of about 180 square meters. This gives a wing loading of less than  5.5 kg/m2. That's roughly an order of magnitude smaller than what gliders typically have (~50), and two orders of magnitude smaller than what transport aircraft may have (~500).

So the wing has very little work to do when carrying the plane. This enables extremely slow flight.

As for the high altitude: stall speed in indicated airspeed does not change with altitude, although all kinds of other weirdish stuff does emerge as air gets really thin. That would, however be a whole can of worms in itself, and it has been opened here in many questions before. For example while indicated airspeed at 96000 ft would remain the same, keeping the plane above stall speed, the true airspeed would have increased significantly, about 20-fold, taking the plane into it's *coffin corner*.

Comment: Well, I'm curious on the plane's stall speed and coffin corner. And if it's that easy to fly that slow that high I wonder why don't more planes do this, and to what altitude a human lying on the Helios (on its middle) could be transported.

Comment: @Giovanni: Why would anyone want to do that?  Either you have a government program paying for research, as with Helios (see your link :-)), or you are a rich person looking to get into record books, like the Perlan glider, or the people who do ultra high skydives.

Comment: @jamesqf I would do it to fly to the edge of space.

Comment: I'm with Giovanni on that one, I'd do it too 

Comment: As to the coffin corner, around FL400 or so the temp, thus the SOS stops going down, then goes back up. According to a calculator I found online, at 96,000 ft 23.5 kts yields a TAS of 180 kts and Mach .309. I don’t think Mach number was a factor. :)

Comment: @Giovanni: So you're a rich person willing to pay a lot of money for the experience :-)

Comment: @Giovanni you did ask many things in one question which is not proper way to do it  here, but I can try and extend my answer a bit later.